# Flutter flavor sourceSet resource not refer flavor folder

Tags: android, flutter, mobile, android-build-flavors, source-sets

In my Flutter mobile app have two flavors with separate `res` folders for each. I have added `sourceSet` in `build.gradle` file, but at runtime the running flavor does not show the relavant resource from flavor folder, instead the `main` folder resources.

Folder structure as below.

```
src
|
flavor1
------res(with sub folders)
|
flavor2
------res(with sub folders)
|
main
------res(with sub folders)
```

`build.gradle` file changes.

```
android {
    sourceSets {
        main {
            java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
            res.srcDirs = ['src/main/res']
            manifest.srcFile 'src/main/AndroidManifest.xml'
        }
        flavor1 {
             res.srcDirs = [
                'src/flavor1/res/drawable-hdpi',
                'src/flavor1/res/drawable-ldpi',
                'src/flavor1/res/drawable-mdpi',
                'src/flavor1/res/drawable-v21',
                'src/flavor1/res/drawable-xhdpi',
                'src/flavor1/res/drawable-xxhdpi',
                'src/flavor1/res/drawable-xxxhdpi',
                'src/flavor1/res/drawable',
                'src/flavor1/res/mipmap-hdpi',
                'src/flavor1/res/mipmap-mdpi',
                'src/flavor1/res/mipmap-xhdpi',
                'src/flavor1/res/mipmap-xxhdpi',
                'src/flavor1/res/mipmap-xxxhdpi',
                'src/flavor1/res/raw',
                'src/flavor1/res/values',
                'src/flavor1/res'
                ]
            manifest.srcFile 'src/flavor1/AndroidManifest.xml'
        }
        flavor2 {
            res.srcDirs = [
                'src/flavor2/res/drawable-hdpi',
                'src/flavor2/res/drawable-ldpi',
                'src/flavor2/res/drawable-mdpi',
                'src/flavor2/res/drawable-v21',
                'src/flavor2/res/drawable-xhdpi',
                'src/flavor2/res/drawable-xxhdpi',
                'src/flavor2/res/drawable-xxxhdpi',
                'src/flavor2/res/drawable',
                'src/flavor2/res/mipmap-hdpi',
                'src/flavor2/res/mipmap-mdpi',
                'src/flavor2/res/mipmap-xhdpi',
                'src/flavor2/res/mipmap-xxhdpi',
                'src/flavor2/res/mipmap-xxxhdpi',
                'src/flavor2/res/raw',
                'src/flavor2/res/values',
                'src/flavor2/res'
                ]
            manifest.srcFile 'src/flavor2/AndroidManifest.xml'
        }
    }

    // Because of flavors and multiple res folders.
    afterEvaluate {
        android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
            tasks.named("generate${variant.name.capitalize()}ResValues")
            .configure { task ->
                 task.outputs.upToDateWhen {false}
            }
        }
    }

    flavorDimensions "app"

    productFlavors {
        flavor1 {
            dimension "app"
            applicationIdSuffix ""
        }
        flavor2 {
            dimension "app"
            applicationIdSuffix ".flavor2"
        }
    }
}
```

Running the `flavor2` app still refers to `main` resources is the issue. I want the respective flavor to refer only the given flavor specific resource folder in runtime.

Answer (score 1):

sourceSet in not necessary, just add product flavors within `app/build.gradle`, folders structure is ok, at compilation time all resources are merged and main folder resources are overridden with flavor resources

just run next command

```
flutter run --flavor flavor2
```

more info here: https://medium.com/@salvatoregiordanoo/flavoring-flutter-392aaa875f36

Comment: Thank you for answering, my implementation was just as you mentioned and it all worked well except that the flavor2 push notification icon is rendering as missing in the device. That's why I have tried with sourceSets, but no luck from that approach.

I just want to fix the push notification icon to also work just as other icons are working as expected. I have created identical file names and drawable/mipmap folders with the each flavor based image. Only this single issue is remaining.

Comment: you need add icon name within android manifest for each flavor

```xml
<meta-data     android:name=”com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon”
android:resource=”@mipmap/ic_notification” />
```

Comment: Android manifest already updated and it is working for flavor1. Resource folders are made for each flavor, but for flavor2 the push notification icon is not rendering (missing in app) flavor2 app icons are working. Strange!